# Как из массива получить значения и разбить их на буквы?

Tags: javascript

Есть какой-то элегантный способ разбить значение на буквы, за тем перейти к следующему значению? У меня что-то одни костыли да ошибки получаются.

```
var key = 0;
var array = [
    [
        'один',
        'два',
        'три'
    ],
    [
        'first',
        'second',
        'third'
    ]
];

array[key]
```

Пример без разбивания на буквы:

```
for(var value = 0; value < array[key].length; value++) {
    console.log(array[key][value]);
}
```

Результат:

```
один
два
три
```

Желаемый результат:

```
о
д
и
н
д
в
а
т
р
и
```

Comment: что значит "разбить его на буквы"? Судя по "желаемому результату" требуется просто склеить значения

Comment: Нужно именно разбить на буквы: з, н, а, ч, е, н, и, е. p.s. запятые не нужны, это я вам для примера. @MedvedevDev

Comment: то есть это не массив? То есть надо пройтись по массиву ... разбить значения на буквы ... а потом эти буквы сложить в одну строку ... чот сложн

Comment: По делу помочь не судьба? Вы же знаете для чего мне нужно "потом эти буквы сложить в одну строку"... @MedvedevDev

Comment: я уверен, что могу помочь, но вы не можете внятно сформулировать вопрос .... в вашем "желаемом результате" строка, в комментариях вы пишете, что вам нужно получить буквы раздельно, но опять не ясно это массив букв или что, не ясно какова структура конечного массива (если массива вообще, а если и так, то какая вложенность, так как в теории вложеность должна быть 3, но кто его знает) должна получиться, так как все что вы сказали "Желаемый результат: значениезначениезначение", что не дает совершенно никакой инфы ибо бессмыслено.

Comment: Эти буквы будут раздельно вставлены в div: 1 div  = 1 буква. Мне не нужен конечный массив, мне нужно только получить значения, разбить на буквы, вернуть каждую букву отдельно: console.log(буква); @MedvedevDev

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
var key = 0;
var array = [
    [
        'значение',
        'значение',
        'значение'
    ],
    [
        'значение',
        'значение',
        'значение',
        'значение',
        'значение'
    ]
];

for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  for(let j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
    for(let k = 0; k < array[i][j].length; k++) {
      document.write(array[i][j][k]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Тройной for ужасает конечно, думал есть вариант проще.)

Comment: @Родион Поляков, сам бы глянул на способ лучше ...

Comment: @Родион Поляков, что это значит?

Comment: Перебор должен быть по ключу (array[key]/key = 0), а не всего массива в целом. @MedvedevDev

Comment: @Родион Поляков, убрать первый цикл, заменить `array[i].length` на `array[0].length`

Comment: А мне наоборот 3 for'а нравятся.

Answer (score 4):

Элементы массива можно перебрать с помощью [метода `forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). Он вызовет функцию `callback` для каждого элемента массива:

```
arr.forEach(function callback(currentValue, index, array) {
    //your iterator
}[, thisArg]);
```

Этот метод применяется именно к массивам. Чтобы пройти по символам из строки, можно сначала воспользоваться [методом split](http://javascript.ru/string/split). Он разобьёт строку на фрагменты и вернёт массив из этих фрагментов:

```
var arr = str.split([separator][, limit]);
```

Получится, например, так:

```js
var array = [
    [
        'один',
        'два',
        'три'
    ],
    [
        'первый',
        'второй',
        'третий'
    ],
    [
        'first',
        'second',
        'third'
    ]
];

array.forEach( function(word) {
  word[0].split('').forEach( function(letter) {
    console.log( letter );
  });
});
```

Но массивы с числовыми индексами быстрее всего перебираются циклом `for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++)`, потому что браузер их "[особым образом оптимизирует](https://learn.javascript.ru/array#%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)". Поэтому быстрее всего отработает [код, предложенный @MedvedevDev](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/718163/208926).

Comment: Кто минусовал, напишите, пожалуйста, за что. Хочу понимать, что не так.

Comment: _Но массивы с числовыми индексами быстрее всего перебираются циклом_ - вранье, без залезания в реализацию движка нельзя сказать что и как будет оптимизировано. Минус я ставил за отсутствие пояснений

Comment: @Grundy Спасибо за критику и пояснение к минусу. По поводу быстроты могу только [процитировать](https://learn.javascript.ru/array#внутреннее-представление-массивов) (сам в этом вопросе некомпетентен): "Современные интерпретаторы стараются оптимизировать их [числовые массивы] и хранить в памяти не в виде хэш-таблицы, а в виде непрерывной области памяти, по которой легко пробежаться от начала до конца."

Comment: Все сводится к тому, что неизвестно во что превратиться код с любым циклом, даже тем же forEach, в процессе выполнения, к внутреннему представлению массива это имеет мало отношения

Answer (score 0):

Если в вопросе было не о скорости, то можно вот так вот:

```
function f(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((s, a) => {
   return s.concat(typeof a === 'string' ? a.length === 1 ? a : f(Array.from(a)) : f(a));
  }, []);
}
```

такой вызов

```
console.log(f([
    [
        'значение',
        'значение',
        'значение'
    ],
    [
        'значение',
        'значение',
        'значение',
        'значение',
        'значение'
    ]
]));
```

вернет

```
[ 'з',
  'н',
  'а',
  'ч',
  'е',
  'н',
  'и',
  'е',
  'з',
  'н',
  'а',
  'ч',
  'е',
  ...
```